# How To differentiate two different Intent to same activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

Am new for android development i need to differentiate intent two different intent to same activity let me explain clearly i have one button  when user press that button it will trigger to other activity in which it will carry some intent value from there based user will enter value based on that i will populate listview from where i trigger the intent from intent suppose if user press the listview from there how to pass the intent with some additional intent values and how to differentiate two intent in receiving activity here is wh

```
at i have tried so far:




 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.add:
                int id=timertrackerdao.getNotesCount();
                if(id>0){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext().getApplicationContext()," Please Finish The Pending Visit",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), AddNotes.class);
                    intent.putExtra("taskid",taskid);
                    intent.addFlags(0);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                }}
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

This is where i will trigger intent from menu bar

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), AddNotes.class);
                    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                    bundle.putInt("addnoteid",id);
                    bundle.putInt("taskid",taskid);
                    bundle.putString("checkin",checkin);
                    intent.addFlags(1);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

This is where i will select the value from listview this is another set of values.  Here in the receiving activity how am trying to differentiate intent:

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
            if(intent.getFlags()==0) {
                if (intent != null) {
                    taskid = intent.getIntExtra("taskid", 0);
                }
            }
    else {
                Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                if (extras != null) {
                    check.setEnabled(false);
                    //  TaskID=extrass.getInt("noteid");
                    id = extras.getInt("addnoteid");
                    date = extras.getString("checkin");
                    TaskID = extras.getInt("taskid");
                    createNotification(date);
                    AddNote(id);
                }
            }
```

Now my question is how to differentiate two intent one from button click and another by clicking listview and how to differentiate that in receiving activity??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put an string with both the intent like this

```
intent.putExtra("from","button");
```

And

```
intent.putExtra("from","listview");
```

Now in another activity

```
    if(getIntent().getStringExtra("from").equals("button"))
{  //do here
}else if(getIntent().getStringExtra("from").equals("listview"))
{   // do here
}
```

Comment: Nice solution.  Do you recommend checking for null for each with the getIntent()?

Answer (score 1):

pass a boolean parameter in the bundle, something like below :

```
intent.putExtra("isFromOptionsMenu",true);
```

Then in receiving activity, check this boolean.

Answer (score 0):

In  calling activity just send the name of the activity to the receiving activity like

```
intent.putExtra("From", "Activity_Name");
```

and in receiving activity differentiate as

```
 Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
    from = bundle.getString("From");
    }
    if (from == "Activity_Name") {    
//first activity
    }
    else{
//second activity
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

just put and extra boolean or activity name or a integer in intent which help you differentiate between activities.

first extract the marker then and based on that extract other informations.

```
intent.putExtra("Name","activity1");
```

in some other activity

```
intent.putExtra("Name","activity2");
```

in receiving activity :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

if(extras != null){
    String name =  extras.getString("Name");
    if(name.equals("activity1")){
       // do something
    }else{
       // do something else
    }
```

Comment: I understand the approaches.  Can you provide an example for each?